# How to make a numpy array with a dictionary's values?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
sam = {1:np.array([1,2,3,4]), 2:np.array([2,4,6,8]) }
```

How can I make a numpy array with the dictionary values like this?

```
arr = ([[1,2,3,4], 
        [2,4,6,8]])
```

I thought `np.fromiter(sam.values(), dtype=np.int16)` might work, but it doesn't work probably because of its dtype.

Are the any functions to do this, instead of using for or any loops?

Comment: Why don't you want to use loops? You have to flatten the iterable  you are passing to `bp.fromiter`, then reshape the resulting array, or convert the `dict_values` into a list and pass it to the normal constructor

Comment: Does the order of rows in `arr` matter?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your comment. This job will be done so many times over the running time, so I want to optimize it and thought using loops wouldn't be the best option.

Comment: Using built-in `list` constructor or `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten will probably be the fastest you can get. Will still have similar overhead to a loop though

Comment: @user3080953 It really doesn't matter. The program searches certain patterns in values by row, and I thought array operations will be faster than using other data structures.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the advice! I will do some tests on it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) the values of your dictionary like this:

```
arr = np.stack(sam.values())

>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries aren't considered ordered unless you are using Python 3.7+. So this is messy, but possible. The idea is to sort `dict.items` by key to give a list of tuples, then extract values.

```
from operator import itemgetter as iget

res = np.array(list(map(iget(1), sorted(sam.items(), key=iget(0)))))

array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
```